# Can someone explain why RK4 is less accurate for very small timesteps?

Tags: ode, numerical-modelling

I am currently working on a project where I have used an RK4 integrator to attempt to solve the three-body problem. An interesting result that I found, was that decreasing the size of the time steps only improved accuracy until a certain point where the accuracy started to decrease. Is this normal for RK4 integrators or have I done something wrong? if this is normal, can anyone explain why this behaviour occurs?

[image: plot of mean squared error vs number of points used]

Comment: While not for RK, [this answer of mine](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/29046/20688) should be relevant.

Comment: How did you get your solution to the three body problem? Are you sure it's "correct"? It's a chaotic system so after any reasonable amount of time, all solutions will have O(1) error.

Comment: @AntonMenshov 's comment should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Another contribution to the topic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3235194/truncation-error-with-growing-step-size. You can reduce the increase of the error to the right by employing Kahan or compensated summation of the step updates. This, roughly, will give an error curve similar to $\max(h^p, \mu, \mu^2/h)$, realistically each term will have a problem-specific constant. $p$ is the order of the method, $\mu$ the machine constant of floating point precision.

Comment: Do you have a code snippet to replicate your simulations ?