# Discrete laplacian 9 point

Tags: pde, matlab, laplacian

I am trying to write a code for 9 point discrete laplacian. I would like to write a matrix and solve the linear system $AU=F$ with gradient conjugate method.
I wrote the matrix this way

```
I=speye(M-1,M-1);
E=sparse(2:M-1,1:M-2,1,M-1,M-1);%matrice con 1 sulla sotto diagonale
T=E+E';
B=-1/6*(T+4*I);
D=1/3*(2*T-10*I);
A=(-kron(I,D)+kron(T,B));
```

And I have a matrix $(M-1)^2(M-1)^2$. Then I wrote F like so

```
F=zeros(M-1);
for i=1:M-1
    for j=1:M-1
        F(i,j)=(dx^2)/12*(8*f(x(i+1),y(j+1))+f(x(i+2),y(j+1)+f(x(i),y(j+1))+...
            f(x(i+1),y(j+2))+f(x(i+1),y(j))));
    end
end
for i=1:M-1
    F(1,i)=F(1,i)+2*term(xmin,xmin+i*dx,scelta)/3+term(xmin,xmin+(i+1)*dx,scelta)/6+...
        term(xmin,xmin+(i-1)*dx,scelta)/6;
    F(i,1)=F(i,1)+2*term(xmin+i*dx,xmin,scelta)/3+term(xmin+(i+1)*dx,xmin,scelta)/6+...
        term(xmin+(i-1)*dx,xmin,scelta)/6;
    F(end,i)=F(end,i)+2*term(xmin+M*dx,xmin+i*dx,scelta)/3+term(xmin+M*dx,xmin+(i+1)*dx,scelta)/6+...
        term(xmin+M*dx,xmin+(i-1)*dx,scelta)/6;
    F(i,end)=F(i,end)+2*term(xmin+i*dx,xmin+M*dx,scelta)/3+term(xmin+(i+1)*dx,xmin+M*dx,scelta)/6+...
        term(xmin+(i-1)*dx,xmin+M*dx,scelta)/6;
end
F(1,1)=F(1,1)-term(xmin,xmin,scelta)/6;
F(1,M-1)=F(1,M-1)-term(xmin,xmin+M*dx,scelta)/6;
F(M-1,1)=F(M-1,1)-term(xmin+M*dx,xmin,scelta)/6;
F(M-1,M-1)=F(M-1,M-1)-term(xmin+M*dx,xmin+M*dx,scelta)/6;

F=reshape(F',[(M-1)^2,1]);
```

where f is the source term.
I don't get why the error gets bigger when reducing by half the dx.

Comment: Did not look into the code, but what `dx` do you start from to observe an increase in the error? Could you already be in the regime where you are dominated by round-off errors? See [this answer of mine on FD round-off vs truncation](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/29046/20688).

Comment: I start dx=0.1, I get errors of about $10^{-2}$ so I don't think to be in the region you are saying...or not?

Comment: yes, I think the problem is different then.

Comment: You'll have to provide more details: PDE, boundary conditions, signification of the various variables, spatial discretisation scheme. And maybe a complete code snippet that we can run.

Comment: What happens at the boundaries, how do you adjust your stencil when there is no next neighbour?